# Can I use interface to navigate between ViewModel on different projects

Tags: mvvmcross

I work on an application with multiple module on different PCL project. I can't create dependency between each module. So, I want to know if it's possible to use interface to navigate from ViewModel in different modules.

Considering two modules (PCL) : ***MyApp.FooModule*** and ***MyApp.BarModule***. Each module has ViewModel, ***FooModuleViewModel*** and ***BarModuleViewModel***. Interfaces are stored on another PCL projet (for example ***MyApp.Interfaces***) referenced by each module. You can see below, my projects dependencies :

***MyApp.Droid*** : MyApp.Interfaces, MyApp.FooModule, MyApp.BarModule

***MyApp.FooModule*** : MyApp.Interfaces

***MyApp.BarModule*** : MyApp.Interfaces

I try to navigate from ***FooModuleViewModel*** to ***BarModuleViewModel***, so in my app setup I would like to write something like this :

```
Mvx.RegisterType<IBarModuleViewModel, BarModuleViewModel>();
```

And in ***FooModuleViewModel*** :

```
ShowViewModel<IBarModuleViewModel>();
```

Actually I have an exception (throw by MvxAndroidViewsContainer) when I achieve that :

```
Exception masked KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for IBarModuleViewModel
```

Is there a way to do this or should I have to use "real" type on ***ShowViewModel*** method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via a few techniques.

Firstly, you could use concrete ViewModel types, but provide some kind of IoC driven route to allow ViewModel's to look up Type information - e.g.

```
public interface IViewModelLookupService
{
    void Register(Type interfaceType, Type concreteType);
    Type Lookup(Type interfaceType);
}
```

A singleton implementation of this could then be filled with code like:

```
lookupService.Register(typeof(IBarModuleViewModel), typeof(BarModuleViewModel));
```

And could then later be used to show view models using:

```
var type = lookupService.Lookup(typeof(IBarModuleViewModel));
ShowViewModel(type);
```

Aside> A variation on this would be to use an `enum` or `string` names instead of interfaces for the lookup.

---

Alternatively, a second approach could be to override your presenters on each platform - these all have an interface:

```
public interface IMvxViewPresenter
{
    void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request);
    void ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint);
}
```

Where the view model request object is: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModelRequest.cs

If you were to override the `void Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)` method, then you could use this to replace the any `MvxViewModelRequest` with an interface `ViewModelType` into a concrete one - e.g. something like:

```
 public override Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
 {
     if (request.ViewModelType.IsInterface)
     {
          var concreteType = // TODO - lookup type here...
          request = new MvxViewModelRequest(concreteType, request.ParameterValues, request.PresentationValues, request.RequestedBy);
     }

     base.Show(request)
 }
```

This would need doing on each platform

---

Other approaches are also possible... Mvx is pretty modular and overrideable really - the wiki pages may help - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki

Comment: I prefer the first approach. After basic tests, it seems to work ! Thank